# Spring form:select not calling converter on form submit

Tags: java, spring, forms, select, converters

I have a very strange and rather inconsistent issue and i'm not sure what could be causing it.  I am changing all my dropdowns in my forms from the non-Spring select to form:select since i find them much cleaner and simpler.  This is my old method which correctly calls the strengthUnit converter and therefore provides a non-null object to my controller :

```
<select name="strengthUnit" path="strengthUnit.name" id="strengthUnit">
                        <option value="0" ${orderedMed.strengthUnit eq null ? 'selected' : ''}></option>
                        <c:forEach items="${strengthUnits}" var="strengthUnitSingle">
                            <option value="${strengthUnitSingle.id}" ${orderedMed.strengthUnit.name eq strengthUnitSingle.name ? 'selected' : ''}>${strengthUnitSingle.name}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
```

I have changed this code to the code below and now the converter is not called and the object is null when it hits the controller :

```
<form:select name="strengthUnit" path="strengthUnit.id" id="strengthUnit">
                        <form:option value="0" label=""></form:option>
                        <form:options items="${strengthUnits}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
                    </form:select>
```

Where is gets even stranger is that this particular entity type is attached to 2 different entities and the form:select tag works in another page!  Both JSP have this line present :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

Here is the strengthUnitConverter class' convert method which is correctly registered in the config class and works using the first method :

```
@Override
public StrengthUnit convert(String id) 
{
    return strengthUnitService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue!  The path attribute needs to point to the entity itself and not its ID :

```
<form:select name="strengthUnit" path="strengthUnit" id="strengthUnit">
                    <form:option value="0" label=""></form:option>
                    <form:options items="${strengthUnits}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
                </form:select>
```

I thought it was working in my other page but found out i was wrong this morning.  With the path corrected i am no longer getting null objects.